# What design patterns are used in an ecommerce web apps?

Tags: oop, design-patterns, architecture, microservices, e-commerce

What design patterns are commonly used or used together in developing e-commerce with microservices or multi-tier layer architecture? Let's say we will write the code using object-oriented language such as Java or .NET 5 just for an example and we develop the client app using a JavaScript framework.

Would the design patterns suggestion change if I choose to implement a microservices architecture?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a pattern called "[Pattern: Microservice Architecture:](https://microservices.io/patterns/microservices.html)"

> Define an architecture that structures the application as a set of
> loosely coupled, collaborating services. This approach corresponds to
> the Y-axis of the Scale Cube. Each service is:
>
> - Highly maintainable and testable - enables rapid and frequent
>   development and deployment
> - Loosely coupled with other services -
>   enables a team to work independently the majority of time on their
>   service(s) without being impacted by changes to other services and
>   without affecting other services
> - Independently deployable - enables a
>   team to deploy their service without having to coordinate with other
>   teams
> - Capable of being developed by a small team - essential for high
>   productivity by avoiding the high communication head of large teams
>
> Services communicate using either synchronous protocols such as
> HTTP/REST or asynchronous protocols such as AMQP. Services can be
> developed and deployed independently of one another. Each service has
> its [own database](https://microservices.io/patterns/data/database-per-service.html) in order to be decoupled from other services. Data
> consistency between services is maintained using the [Saga pattern](https://microservices.io/patterns/data/saga.html)
>
> To learn more about the nature of a service, please [read this article](http://chrisrichardson.net/post/microservices/general/2019/02/16/whats-a-service-part-1.html).

And [e-commerce application](https://microservices.io/patterns/microservices.html) is considered as an example to apply pattern: Microservice Architecture.

So it is possible to create multiple services divided by entities or business domains:

- customers
- inventory
- shipping

Then it is necessary provide the way of communication among services. It can be event streaming platform [Kafka](https://kafka.apache.org).